# How to request a token from CRM?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm-2016, bearer-token

**Why does it still on CreateFromResourceUrlAsync?**

When attempting to execute this:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function returns the Authority Url (OAuth Endpoint) and Resource Url (Dynamics 365 Url)
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public AuthenticationParameters DiscoverAuthority()
{
    AuthenticationParameters authParamters = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync
        (new Uri(BaseOrganizationApiUrl + "/api/data/")).Result;
    return authParamters;
}
```

It stalls on the .Result line above.

**What am I doing wrong?**

1. We're on CRM 2016
2. When pointing a regular web browser to that same URI: BaseOrganizationApiUrl + "/api/data/" ... it will ask for credentials, and keep asking for credentials, even though that user *does* exist, and *can sign in* regularly.
3. I've attempted both http and https.

**How do I get the AuthenticationParameters in order to get the OAuthToken?**

Comment: This could be an issue with `.Result`. Async methods should almost always be awaited. Try refactoring your code to use `await AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(..`

Comment: Yes indeed I've tried that originally